# RTSP RTP client streaming, timestamp, live555

Tags: streaming, timestamp, rtsp, rtp, live555

I have an IP camera that is located in a different country (*with a different time zone*) and that has it's own date-time values applied, (*for example:~2012-04-16 11:30:00*) then the one my PC is located at. (*so my PC's time for example is ~2012-14-16 06:10:00*)

**My purpose:**
When streaming, i need to get this date-time value that is set in **camera** ("11:30:00")
(*I'm not interested in a current local time of my PC*).

- **Is there any way to calculate camera's date-time value from RTP's timestamp**?
- Is there any other approach?

I'm using a Live555 library, and for frame's date-time retrieval I was using a "presentation time" value, but this gives me a local time of my PC (not the time that is set in my camera)

So I'm stuck here..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the RFC on RTP packet [layout](http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/rtp.htm)

Note that the Timestamp is in the RTP packet at **0x32**. This is the timestamp from the camera that encoded the stream.

For a CPP [implementation](http://snipplr.com/view/57979/rtp-packet-handler/), processing RTP packet and headers including the timestamp , see the link.

Java implementation of RTP packet handler [here](http://snipplr.com/view/57978/rtp-packet-handler/)