# Grabbing video with RTSP over TCP

Tags: tcp, h.264, rtsp, rtp

I want to retrieve some video data from a device with RTSP.

RTSP over UDP works well, but I need it over TCP.

After issuing the RTSP commands, I receive RTPs but I do not how to handle them here.
The payload is as follows: $[channel - 1 byte][length - 2bytes][data]

The thing is that I receive such packets and sometimes further packets where channel is 10 or 99 etc.

So could anyone please provide some input on how to handle the payload ?

Answer (score 2):

You have it all in [RFC 2326 "Real Time Streaming Protocol (RTSP)"](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2326.txt). You need "10.12 Embedded (Interleaved) Binary Data":

> Stream data such as RTP packets is encapsulated by an ASCII dollar sign (24 hexadecimal), followed by a one-byte channel identifier, followed by the length of the encapsulated binary data as a binary, two-byte integer in network byte order. The stream data follows immediately afterwards, without a CRLF, but including the upper-layer  protocol headers. Each $ block contains exactly one upper-layer protocol data unit, e.g., one RTP packet.

There is a small example there as well:

```
 S->C: $\000{2 byte length}{"length" bytes data, w/RTP header}
 S->C: $\000{2 byte length}{"length" bytes data, w/RTP header}
 S->C: $\001{2 byte length}{"length" bytes  RTCP packet}
```

Comment: That's the exact document that I've followed; But I do not find that data enough. Moreover, I've inspected the input with Wireshark and saw this message: [Malformed Packet: RTP]. Should I concatenate the all payloads for a RTP until receiving another payload like in the fist two lines you depicted ? Also, the payload is quite large while the data length only says 22 bytes. And where can I grab the PPS and SPS from in this case ?

Comment: It should be basically the same data you otherwise receive over UDP.

Answer (score 1):

Getting PPS is IMO straightforward and does not really require parseing the packet.

Your request for SPS , im guessing , will require getting into the packet ( i dont think you need to worry about WS msg 'invalid packet'.

What about using Type at PT at 0x09 ?

see [here](http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/rtp.htm#PT,%20Payload%20Type) for packet description

sample implementations of unpacking RTP in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10171542/rtsp-rtp-client-streaming-timestamp-live555/10195274#10195274)

try looking [here](http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-mmusic-sdp-tcpmedia-00.txt) for more info related to RTSP control and SDP over TCP. If you are getting into inspecting the details of the RTSP session/conversation and the messaging details about control protocol selection for the respective tracks in your video. If u can get your answer without a diversion into SDP / RTCP then , obviously, thats faster/better.

Answer (score 1):

this is the packet format for TCP/RTP :

```
[$ - 1byte][Transport Channel - 1byte][RTP data length - 2bytes][RTP data]
```

the rest is like upd

for more info read [process raw rtp packets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665217/how-to-process-raw-udp-packets-so-that-they-can-be-decoded-by-a-decoder-filter-i)

Answer (score 0):

Just explain something, I'm working for this as well, If you want use RTSP over TCP, please be careful about your socket reading code.
The suitable socket process like below:

```
while (socket.connected) {
  char magic = socket.read a char;
  if (magic == '$') {  // is a RTP over TCP packet
     byte channel = socket.read 1 byte;
     unsigned short len = socket.read 2 byte; // len = ((byte1 & 0xFF) << 8) + (byte2 &0xFF);
     int readTotal = 0;
     byte rtpPacket[len];
     while (readTotal < len) {
         // read remaing bytes to rtpPacket from index readTotal
         int r = socket.read(rtpPacket, readTotal, len - readTotal); 
         if (r > 0)
            readTotal += r;
         else    // -1 means socket read error
            break;   
     }
     // now we get full RTP packet, process it!
     call back channel, rtpPacket;
  } else {  // is RTSP protocol response
     string array header;
     while (line = socket.readline() != null) {
        if (line == "") {
           int body_len = Parse header "Content-Length";
           byte body[body_len];
           int readBody = 0;
           while (readBody < body_len) {
              int r = socket.read(body, readBody, body_len - readBody);
              if (r>0)
                readBody += r;
              else
                break;
           }

           // Now we get full header, body of RTSP response, process it
           Callback header, body;   
        } else {
           header.add(line);
        }
     }
  }
}
```